# How to Remove Variable Border?

Tags: sublimetext2

I do not want to appear in this border when writing.

my theme is soda. 
installed package: sublimelint and sublimerepl. 
Language: Python

Problem Solved. I deleted the sublimelint package

[image: Screenshot showing some code]

Comment: When does this border appear? When does it disappear? Where was your cursor when the picture was taken? What theme are you using?

Comment: When I was defined variable or function. mouse out of sublimetext. and my theme is soda. installed package: sublimelint and sublimerepl. Language: Python. http://i.imm.io/1bCNh.png